# Reading Yahoo Finance: Extract a smaller table from a bigger table Python (historical low price)

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

I have a table from yahoo finance with one year of data

The table is like the figure below

[image]

[image]

I want to join two columns of this table to make a new one. I want the column date and price

Does anyone can give me a tip?

Comment: Your question looks really mess! Try to [edit] it and fix it!

Comment: Like the other comment, please improve the layout of question. The simplest you should do is put ```  around your code and outputs. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Your initial post (Revisions 1 and 2) which included an MRE and no images was much closer to what is expected of questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the first part of your question, where you only want to see a table (pandas dataframe) with columns date and low.

Column selection in pandas is very easy. You put the list of columns you like to see in a python list, and then pass it to dataframe in way you subset.

```
mycolumns = ["date", "low"]
newdf = bvsp2[mycolumns]
print(newdf)
```

Output

```
          date      low
0   2017-02-16  67661.0
1   2017-02-17  67158.0
2   2017-02-20  67756.0
3   2017-02-21  68536.0
4   2017-02-22  68282.0
..         ...      ...
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help and the feedback. I could also do it with 'concat'

Comment: Frame = pd.concat([bvsp2.iloc[:,0], bvsp2.iloc[:,4], bvsp2.iloc[:,6]], axis=1)